# how can I set only one text from <a attribute list?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here, I am trying to update input type a attribute text only, if the `obj.idPartnerOffice == json.idPartnerOffice` condition is true. How can I update project name only ?

```js
 if (json.idPartnerProject == "0") {
                json.idPartnerProject = Math.random();
                hidJson.Form5.Projects.push(json);
                $("#divbindProjectlist").append('<a href="#" id="anchorproject1" class="list-group-item projectList" >' + json.ProjectName + '<input type="hidden" name="hiddenproject1" class="hidprojectId" value="' + json.idPartnerProject + '" /></a>');
            }
            else {
                $.each(hidJson.Form5.Projects, function (i, obj) {
                    if (obj.idPartnerProject == json.idPartnerProject) {
                        hidJson.Form5.Projects[i] = json;
                        $("#anchorproject1").html(json.ProjectName).append('<input type="hidden" name="hiddenproject1" class="hidprojectId" value="' + json.idPartnerProject + '" />');
                    }
                });


            }
```

Here is image for html view with list of projects,
[image]

Now, All the hidden field values are changed. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: if I am changing the 1st <a text, that is 'asdfasd' to something like 'aaaa' then, how to update ?

Comment: are you wanting to change obj  variable or json variable?

Comment: FWIW, you misspelled `href` as `herf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to move the hidden fields (which are missing name attributes btw) outside of the anchor tags (they're not clickable elements, anyway), add an id attribute to the anchors:

```
<a href="#" id="anchorproject1" class="list-group-item projectList">asdfasd</a>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenproject1" class="hidprojectId" value="12345" />
```

and then use some jquery to access the text:

```
$("#anchorproject1").html("aaaaaa");
```

---

Edit:

You're in danger of having this question flagged for closure - you started off asking how to change the text in the anchor tag, and now you're asking about the hidden fields? Make up your mind - what do you actually need help with?

Comment: I have added hiddenfield name. But now all the hiddendfield values are changed and if I am select 2st <a html then changing 1st <a html. how to fix it? I have updated question.

Comment: @AbhiJA The hidden field values have changed because you're using `json.idPartnerProject = Math.random();` and then putting `value="' + json.idPartnerProject + '"`. Every time you run this, `Math.random()` will generate a new value - Is that not what you want?

Comment: `if (json.idPartnerProject == "0")` then here is happening only new `idPartnerProject`. But in `else` case still containing existing id. So I want to bind `if (obj.idPartnerProject == json.idPartnerProject)` Project name to <a , not to all <a. But here is happening existing `idPartnerProject` all changing and keeping same value. How can I solve this?

Comment: The id attribute should be unique for any given element on the page. Looking at your latest screenshot, you are assigning the same `id="anchorproject1"` to every anchor tag, which means that `$("#anchorproject1")` will reference every anchor tag - you need to give each anchor tag a unique id, like anchorproject1, anchorproject2, etc. Similarly, you probably don't want to assign `name="hiddenproject1"` to every hidden field, but the name attribute isn't as strict as the id attribute, so technically, you're OK there.